# ICustomTypeProvider or DynamicObject

Tags: wpf, binding, dynamicobject, icustomtypedescriptor

I'm looking to bind to a class that exposes its properties dynamically as per the code below. It seems that both ICustomTypeProvider and DynamicObject would work for this. Can anybody explain why I might want to use one over the other?

```
void CreateDynamicItem()
    {
        var di = new DynamicItem();
        di.AddProperty("Age", 16, typeof(int));
        di.AddProperty("Height", 5.2, typeof(double));
    }

<StackPanel>
    <Slider Value="{Binding Age}" />
    <Slider Value="{Binding Height}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer here [Binding to Dynamic Properties with ICustomTypeProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/04/26/binding-to-dynamic-properties-with-icustomtypeprovider-silverlight-5-beta.aspx)  under "What about WPF and DLR?"

> The DLR objects such as ExpandoObject or DynamicObject (or any other implementation of the IDynamicMetaObjectProvider interface) do not carry any type information for their properties. The data binding engine, on the other hand, needs to get this information in order to perform type conversion for anything other than String.